# .fadeIn() does not fire in IE version less than 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My CSS:

```
#midC {
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */ 
}
```

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#midC').load(function() {  
        $('#midC').fadeIn('slow');  
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="theImages/topLogo_temp.png" id=midC />
```

The above code work in CSS and IE > 9. Is there anyway to make it work less than version 9? The image sometime appears and sometime doesn't on IE8.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: What element type is `#midC` and why do you expect it to `load` after the `document` is already `ready`?

Comment: Sorry about that... Updated my question :)

Comment: Maybe it's already loaded?

Comment: I can remove the `load()` and will it work?

Comment: Why `load` is being used ?

Comment: Great point. It will be removed and tested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are big caveats to using the `load` event with images.  From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> ```
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache
> ```

The most common I have seen with IE 8 is the last point, where the image is already loaded in the browser cache.

Comment: Once the LOAD function was deleted, the image loaded fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `JavaScript`, the `window.onload` event fires after all the images has been loaded, so, I think you may use following instead of `document`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#midC').fadeIn('slow');  
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/VsDYE/)
Don't have `IE8` to test it but it should work.

Comment: Removing the LOAD event also did the trick as well... Thanks for the answer. UPVOTED.

Comment: @SiKni8, Glad to know :-)